# How can I redirect a command's input and output through VNC?

Tags: tty, vnc, terminal-emulator

I need to create a VNC sesion, with a linux command running on it. LinuxVNC can do the trick, but LinuxVNC only allows me to export ttys. There are only 64 ttys available on linux, but this amount is not enough for me, is there a way to increase this number? This might allow me to use LinuxVNC.

If not, how how can I create a VNC sesion with a command's input and output on it? Proxmox's vncterm was designed for this but I'm having lots of issues and trying to find an alternative, without luck so far.

My specific case, I'm building an LXD driver for OpenNebula. OpenNebula has a VNC client that lets me attach to a console inside virtual machines deployed. Because I couldn't increase the tty's limit, I can't execute "lxc exec login" for each deployed container and redirect it's output to another tty in order to export this tty using linuxvnc. VNCterm is great for me but was built for proxmox. It might be installed on other debian based systems but there might be dependencies issues and this solution needs to work fine, out of the box, and also on other Linux distros. Besides, I'm having other issues with Proxmox's VNCTerm.

Any idea?
Thanks in advanced